# How the input field is able to be clicked by the user which is hidden?

Tags: html, css

How does the css3 `:checked` work with hidden element?

I found the custom checkboxes and radio butons [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nUKpQ/).

Where firstly set hidden to the radio button:

```
input[type=radio]{display: none;}
```

And applied `:before pseudo` element for the label to make appear like radio button before the label.

But now after user checks the button then the following css is applied to display the check.

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before{
```

So, now my question is that how the radio button is checkable and uncheckable by the user where the example uses `display: none` to the radio button and for that nothing pseudo element is created but only for label before, and it uses 
`input[type=radio]:checked` to display custom button.

But how is the radio button is accessible to check or uncheck which is hidden?

Comment: that's because of the internal implemenation of `for` attribute which only a `label` has. Without that special attribute, I think we have to use script, no other way. Another way (without using `for`) is just wrap the hidden input field in the `label`, then interacting with the label is the way to interact with the inner hidden input field.

Answer (score 0):

There's two key points here:

1. A checkbox has a checked status regardless of if it is shown. Just because it is `style='display: none'` doesn't mean it's not checked or unchecked.
2. A label for a checkbox (Has the `for` attribute set to it's id or the `input` is defined in it), when clicked, will change the status of the checkbox, even if that checkbox isn't visible.

So based on that, what you have is a label for each checkbox shown, then a CSS rule that applies to `label` elements that occur directly after an `input` which is `:checked` that define a pseudo-element before it. By clicking the label you toggle the invisible checkbox and you get this result.